# Issues with Google GeoLocation API

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am trying to get location co-ordinates based on WiFi access point details using Google GeoLocation API. The issue is I am always returned the same co-ordinate for every request.
The URL to which I am passing my JSON request is: `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MY_API`

The JSON data that I am passing is:

```
{
    "radioType":"wcdma",
    "homeMobileNetworkCode":"0",
    "homeMobileCountryCode":"234",
    "carrier":"BT",
    "wifiAccessPoints":
    {
        "signalStrength":-73,
        "age":0,
        "macAddress":"BSSID HERE",
        "channel":6
    }
}
```

I am UK based, which is why I have set MNC to 234. Also, I can only use wifi for location services as there is no GPS installed in the current configuration.
The response that I always receive from Google is:

```
{ 
    "location": 
    {  
        "lat": 51.517098999999995,  
        "lng": -0.146084 
    }, 
    "accuracy": 18000.0
}
```

I receive that response for all my requests, irrespective of any BSSID that I pass as request. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong here? I am passing this data as a POST request using Java (using the standard HTTP Connection listed [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/))

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the Google Geolocation API Documentation: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/#cell_tower_object

You can see the 'cellTowers' and 'wifiAccessPoints' sections are setup to use JSON Arrays.

So, to fix your example, it should look like this:

```
{
    "radioType":"wcdma",
    "homeMobileNetworkCode":"0",
    "homeMobileCountryCode":"234",
    "carrier":"BT",
    "wifiAccessPoints":
    [{
        "signalStrength":-73,
        "age":0,
        "macAddress":"BSSID HERE",
        "channel":6
    }]
}
```